# Error handling in a REST API

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented a small REST API using WebApi 2 and NHibernate for ORM.

When non-existent id is supplied, NHibernate will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. So I thought I would rethrow a custom exception and then handle all the error logging and returning (there is some logic to different errors/environments) to the client in one place - the `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute`.

Basically the question is : is this okay or I'm using the custom exception to handle normal flow? How can I improve this?

Example `EntityController` method:

```
// GET: api/Entity/5
[ApiExceptionFilter]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(
            _mapper.Map<Entity, EntityDTO>(
                _repository.GetById<Entity>(id)));
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(ex);
    }
}
```

`Repository`

```
public T GetById<T>(int id) where T : Entity
{
    return _session.Value.Query<T>().First(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

`NotFoundException`:

```
public class NotFoundException : ApiException
{
    private static readonly string CustomMessage = "Nothing found! :( Try refining the arguments";

    public NotFoundException(System.Exception ex)
        : base(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, CustomMessage, ex)
    { }
}
```

And finally, `ApiExceptionFilterAttribute`

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        _logger.Log(context.Exception);
        var exception = context.Exception as ApiException;
        if (exception != null)
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(exception.StatusCode, exception.Message);
        }
// if not dev or test environment, non-user-friendly exceptions will be returned as generic 500 error
#if !(DEBUG || TEST) 
        else
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something went wrong");
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your real code?

Comment: Yes. Well, except that I swapped the entity classname for Entity

Comment: ...so where is the `_logger` defined? The `ExceptionFilterAttribute` does not provide such field.

Comment: you got me..  in my source its // TODO: _logger.Log(context.Exception)

Answer (score 1):

You're really dragging your Web API through a performance drag by throwing an exception -- especially for something as trivial as a `GetById` returning a `null`. You could deal with the non-existence of the `id` upfront and save yourself the trouble...

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var entity = _repository.GetById<Entity>(id);
    if (entity == null)
    {
        // log here...
        // then I would recommend you return a meaningful statuscode of 4xx instead
        // of the 500 (internal error) you are doing at the moment.
    }
    else
    {
        // do your mapping and return the 200 (OK) status code on a success
    }
}
```

then change your repository to look like this:

```
public class Repository<T>
    where T : IEntity
{   
    public T GetById(int id)
    {   
        return _session.Value.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to provide repository code. Added.
The trick is that .First() throws an exception if doesnt find anything

Comment: @evictednoise - I you should be using `FirstOrDefault()`. I have provided a sample in my answer.

Comment: I disagree, as the search+if/else section of code will then be duplicated on every part of the src that implements the same logic. IMO the concrete exception type +  global filter approach although maybe less performance efficient, its a lot cleaner in terms of code duplication.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo - In regards to your concern about code duplication, I agree that the code provided does not illustrate a cleaner implementation... Regardless, throwing an exception on conditional logic that does something so easy like `GetById`is not the right solution.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo --- Maybe you could help illustrate your idea? Because I don't see the gains of repeating a `try/catch` block and throwing exceptions versus an `if (obj == null) {...} else {...}` block. The latter just reads easier to me... I guess it is a matter of opinion.